# Android application for simple google map integration for location finding

Tags: android

When am try to run my android application i got screen like this 
[image]

guide me to fix this issue

Comment: from play store search for google play services and update it

Comment: your Emulator or device haven't installed updated version of google play services.

Comment: Thank u for this useful information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I made mistake this  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'

In my dependencies  actually it is the issue now I reduced it like the above showed image now it is working fine

Answer (score 0):

Go to SDK manager and select the Google play services at extras and update it. 
clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Thanks for your guidence